# How to access Dispatcher object in C# DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, dispatcher

Currently i am using the below code in WPF. But now i need to implement the same in a DLL without using WPF.(There is no UI)

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Kepware.ClientAce.OpcDaClient.DaServerMgt.DataChangedEventHandler(DataChanged), DCevHndlrArray);
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do it? Your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't, no guarantee that your DLL will run in a WPF app.  Use SynchronizationContext.Current instead.  Copy it in your constructor so you can call its Post() method later.

Answer (score 4):

That is no Problem as long as you Reference the 3 Main Components of the WPF Framework

- PresentationCore.dll
- PresentationFramework.dll
- WindowsBase.dll

Than you are able to use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Just an Advice ... `Dispatcher.Invoke(..)` and `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(..)` are the two common ways to Dispatch actions back to the Surface. But as long as you NOT use `Application.Dispatcher` you are not able to ensure that you action will be executed in the same dispatcher than you UI elements are running. Since you are able to run Multiple Dispatcher in one `AppDomain` or if your DLL is not loaded into your UI `AppDomain` you could be run into a bug.

Answer (score 0):

if the dll is used inside a wpf application and you include the PresentationFramework assembly, you shuld be able to use `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher`

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Required references:

PresentationFramework.dll (For Application object), and its dependencies:

System.Xaml.dll
WindowsBase.dll